# want to implement option at the time of call

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
```

How can i use these actions and where?

I want to give options to the user at the time of call in the android. Just like if i make a call it should first ask from where you want to make a call.

Basically i want to give option to launch my application when phone icon is pressed in the android device in home screen. So is it possible?

Comment: those are actions normally used in explicit intent and can you make your qtn little more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add those filters to the activity you want to launch in manifest ( i hope you know how to call using code and the permissions required)

```
   <activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>


    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: it works fine at the time of call but now is it possible  to use this option at the time of phone button pressed?

Comment: it depends on the phone you are using as they might be using their on dialer and soft key... if there is a hardware call button this will work-- as we dont know what intent the manufacturer is calling :) sry

Comment: ok np but it works for me to get into the right direction :-)